# What's the difference between service type: NodePort & LoadBalancer

Tags: kubernetes

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx 
  labels:
    name: nginx
spec:
  ports:
    # the port that this service should serve on
  - port: 80 
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30000 
  selector:
    name: nginx
  type: NodePort
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx 
  labels:
    name: nginx
spec:
  ports:
    # the port that this service should serve on
  - port: 80 
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30000 
  selector:
    name: nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Two methods all support loadbalancer.
And the port range is between 30000-32000,  why?
If I want to use port 3000, what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/services.html#type-nodeport:

> If you set the type field to "NodePort", the Kubernetes master will
>   allocate a port from a flag-configured range (default: 30000-32767).

There is a risk of low ports conflict with real things running on host. That's the reason, why ports are limited. You are still able to configure kube-apiserver - flag `--service-node-port-range=`

http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/admin/kube-apiserver.html

Comment: This answer explains what NodePort is but doesn't how it is different from LoadBalancer in practice, which I believe is what the OP asked.

Comment: the url does not exist